# How To: Best way to draw table in console app (C#)

Tags: c#, console, drawing

I have an interesting question.
Imagine I have a lot of data changing in very fast intervals.
I want to display that data as a table in console app. f.ex:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Column 1     |    Column 2     |    Column 3     |    Column 4     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 |                 |                 |                 |
|                 |                 |                 |                 |
|                 |                 |                 |                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to keep things fast and how to fix column widths ? I know how to do that in java, but I don't how it's done in C#.

Comment: what if you provide your Java solution so one can help you in translating into C#?
But have a look at the String class with Length/PadLeft/PadRight/...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
static int tableWidth = 73;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Clear();
    PrintLine();
    PrintRow("Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4");
    PrintLine();
    PrintRow("", "", "", "");
    PrintRow("", "", "", "");
    PrintLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void PrintLine()
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', tableWidth));
}

static void PrintRow(params string[] columns)
{
    int width = (tableWidth - columns.Length) / columns.Length;
    string row = "|";

    foreach (string column in columns)
    {
        row += AlignCentre(column, width) + "|";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(row);
}

static string AlignCentre(string text, int width)
{
    text = text.Length > width ? text.Substring(0, width - 3) + "..." : text;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return new string(' ', width);
    }
    else
    {
        return text.PadRight(width - (width - text.Length) / 2).PadLeft(width);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 175):

Use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) with alignment values.

For example:

```
String.Format("|{0,5}|{1,5}|{2,5}|{3,5}|", arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

To create one formatted row.

Comment: Wouldn't that print the same value four times?

Comment: Yeah, you should fix : String.Format("|{0,10}|{1,10}|{2,10}|{3,10}|", arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);

Comment: If you don't need table edges and corners, this works well. Don't forget to use the PadRight(x) or PadLeft(x) to help you with your spacing. For what I needed, I just needed something easy to read, and after removing the |s this did the trick.

Comment: Use `-` for left-align content, e.g: `{0,-5}`

Comment: This is so much simpler and better than many aforementioned libraries especially if this is a progressive log output to a console, since many above takes a complete data structure in order to enclose everything in a table with borders and all.

For C# string interpolation, use `$"{interpolated,n:f}"` where `n` is your optional alignment (as above) and `f` is your optional format string.

Comment: You could also do Console.WriteLine(<example string above>);

Answer (score 55):

There're several open-source libraries which allow console table formatting, ranging from simple (like the code samples in the answers here) to more advanced.

### ConsoleTable

Judging by NuGet stats, the most popular library for formatting tables is [ConsoleTables](https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/ConsoleTables). Tables are constructed like this (from the readme file):

```
var table = new ConsoleTable("one", "two", "three");
table.AddRow(1, 2, 3)
     .AddRow("this line should be longer", "yes it is", "oh");
```

Tables can be formatted using one of the predefined styles. It'll look like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| one                        | two       | three |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1                          | 2         | 3     |
--------------------------------------------------
| this line should be longer | yes it is | oh    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

This library expects single-line cells with no formatting.

There're a couple of libraries based on ConsoleTable with slightly extended feature sets, like more line styles.

### CsConsoleFormat

If you need more complex formatting, you can use [CsConsoleFormat](https://github.com/Athari/CsConsoleFormat).† Here's a table generated from a process list (from a sample project):

```
new Grid { Stroke = StrokeHeader, StrokeColor = DarkGray }
    .AddColumns(
        new Column { Width = GridLength.Auto },
        new Column { Width = GridLength.Auto, MaxWidth = 20 },
        new Column { Width = GridLength.Star(1) },
        new Column { Width = GridLength.Auto }
    )
    .AddChildren(
        new Cell { Stroke = StrokeHeader, Color = White }
            .AddChildren("Id"),
        new Cell { Stroke = StrokeHeader, Color = White }
            .AddChildren("Name"),
        new Cell { Stroke = StrokeHeader, Color = White }
            .AddChildren("Main Window Title"),
        new Cell { Stroke = StrokeHeader, Color = White }
            .AddChildren("Private Memory"),
        processes.Select(process => new[] {
            new Cell { Stroke = StrokeRight }
                .AddChildren(process.Id),
            new Cell { Stroke = StrokeRight, Color = Yellow, TextWrap = TextWrapping.NoWrap }
                .AddChildren(process.ProcessName),
            new Cell { Stroke = StrokeRight, Color = White, TextWrap = TextWrapping.NoWrap }
                .AddChildren(process.MainWindowTitle),
            new Cell { Stroke = LineThickness.None, Align = HorizontalAlignment.Right }
                .AddChildren(process.PrivateMemorySize64.ToString("n0")),
        })
    )
```

The end result will look like this:

[image]

It supports any kind of table lines (several included and customizable), multi-line cells with word wrap, colors, columns growing based on content or percentage, text alignment etc.

<sub>† CsConsoleFormat was developed by me.</sub>

Comment: I know it's pretty old, but how can I create a multi line cells? I didn't find it anywhere

Comment: @Morta1 Neither this answer nor CsConsoleFormat library are old. If you're using CsConsoleFormat, you can either insert the line breaks manually ("\n" in strings inside cells) and it will be handled correctly, or let the library wrap text automatically (it's the default, so you just don't add `TextWrap = TextWrapping.NoWrap` unlike in the example above).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, is there a way to do it with ConsoleTable?

Comment: @Morta1 No. I don't think any of the simple libraries support that.

Comment: Hi @Athari, first of all, CsConsoleFormat is great. Is it possible to do conditional coloring on a table cell? For example, if the text is "true", then the color is green, if it's "false", then the color is red.

Comment: @HarveyDarvey Something like `new Cell(text) { Color = text == "true" ? Green : Red }`. If you have many tables with similar formatting rules, you can put that code into some function, be it for cell, row, or whole table.

Comment: @Athari Probably I am missing something here, but what statement does the actual rendering for `CsConsoleFormat`? I try `grid.Render(new ConsoleBuffer());` and `ConsoleRenderer.RenderDocument(grid);` and ``ConsoleRenderer.RenderDocument(new Document(grid));``, and it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I had to add the columns like so: `grid.Columns.Add(new Column{}, ...` (as columns) and not as children...

Answer (score 45):

**Edit:** thanks to @superlogical, you can now find and improve the following code in [github](https://github.com/Robert-McGinley/TableParser)!

---

I wrote this class based on some ideas here. The columns width is optimal, an it can handle object arrays with this simple API:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  IEnumerable<Tuple<int, string, string>> authors =
    new[]
    {
      Tuple.Create(1, "Isaac", "Asimov"),
      Tuple.Create(2, "Robert", "Heinlein"),
      Tuple.Create(3, "Frank", "Herbert"),
      Tuple.Create(4, "Aldous", "Huxley"),
    };

  Console.WriteLine(authors.ToStringTable(
    new[] {"Id", "First Name", "Surname"},
    a => a.Item1, a => a.Item2, a => a.Item3));

  /* Result:        
  | Id | First Name | Surname  |
  |----------------------------|
  | 1  | Isaac      | Asimov   |
  | 2  | Robert     | Heinlein |
  | 3  | Frank      | Herbert  |
  | 4  | Aldous     | Huxley   |
  */
}
```

Here is the class:

```
public static class TableParser
{
  public static string ToStringTable<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> values,
    string[] columnHeaders,
    params Func<T, object>[] valueSelectors)
  {
    return ToStringTable(values.ToArray(), columnHeaders, valueSelectors);
  }

  public static string ToStringTable<T>(
    this T[] values,
    string[] columnHeaders,
    params Func<T, object>[] valueSelectors)
  {
    Debug.Assert(columnHeaders.Length == valueSelectors.Length);

    var arrValues = new string[values.Length + 1, valueSelectors.Length];

    // Fill headers
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < arrValues.GetLength(1); colIndex++)
    {
      arrValues[0, colIndex] = columnHeaders[colIndex];
    }

    // Fill table rows
    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < arrValues.GetLength(0); rowIndex++)
    {
      for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < arrValues.GetLength(1); colIndex++)
      {
        arrValues[rowIndex, colIndex] = valueSelectors[colIndex]
          .Invoke(values[rowIndex - 1]).ToString();
      }
    }

    return ToStringTable(arrValues);
  }

  public static string ToStringTable(this string[,] arrValues)
  {
    int[] maxColumnsWidth = GetMaxColumnsWidth(arrValues);
    var headerSpliter = new string('-', maxColumnsWidth.Sum(i => i + 3) - 1);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < arrValues.GetLength(0); rowIndex++)
    {
      for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < arrValues.GetLength(1); colIndex++)
      {
        // Print cell
        string cell = arrValues[rowIndex, colIndex];
        cell = cell.PadRight(maxColumnsWidth[colIndex]);
        sb.Append(" | ");
        sb.Append(cell);
      }

      // Print end of line
      sb.Append(" | ");
      sb.AppendLine();

      // Print splitter
      if (rowIndex == 0)
      {
        sb.AppendFormat(" |{0}| ", headerSpliter);
        sb.AppendLine();
      }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
  }

  private static int[] GetMaxColumnsWidth(string[,] arrValues)
  {
    var maxColumnsWidth = new int[arrValues.GetLength(1)];
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < arrValues.GetLength(1); colIndex++)
    {
      for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < arrValues.GetLength(0); rowIndex++)
      {
        int newLength = arrValues[rowIndex, colIndex].Length;
        int oldLength = maxColumnsWidth[colIndex];

        if (newLength > oldLength)
        {
          maxColumnsWidth[colIndex] = newLength;
        }
      }
    }

    return maxColumnsWidth;
  }
}
```

---

**Edit:** I added a minor improvement - if you want the column headers to be the property name, add the following method to `TableParser` (note that it will be a bit slower due to reflection):

```
public static string ToStringTable<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> values,
    params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] valueSelectors)
{
  var headers = valueSelectors.Select(func => GetProperty(func).Name).ToArray();
  var selectors = valueSelectors.Select(exp => exp.Compile()).ToArray();
  return TableParser.ToStringTable(values, headers, selectors);
}

private static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expresstion)
{
  if (expresstion.Body is UnaryExpression)
  {
    if ((expresstion.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand is MemberExpression)
    {
      return ((expresstion.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
    }
  }

  if ((expresstion.Body is MemberExpression))
  {
    return (expresstion.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Where is the GetProperty method?

Comment: @superlogical, it has been added at the bottom of the answer. Thank you for noticing.

Comment: I like the self-contained extension method style compared to the other answers on here. Thanks!

Comment: awesome i used it and it work perfectly, Just edited this `arrValues[rowIndex, colIndex] = valueSelectors[colIndex].Invoke(values[rowIndex - 1]).ToString();` to `var val = valueSelectors[colIndex].Invoke(values[rowIndex - 1]);
                    arrValues[rowIndex, colIndex] = val == null ? "null" : val.ToString();` in this way it shows null.

Comment: This works great, until you start working with non-unicode characters. Then the width gets all messed up.

Comment: `ToStringTable(this string[,] arrValues)` works great but the extension methods are absolutely terrible code. Reflection, typing, Params of Func<string, object> that have to be hard coded to a specific length. I hated them so much I started refactoring this code only to find out regular old `ToStringTable(this string[,] arrValues)`  does exactly what you need. The extension methods are just an overly complicated way of creating the string[,]. A+ on `ToStringTable(this string[,] arrValues)`, F-- on the extension methods. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @user875234 first of all this lib was not meant for production use, only for unit testing and such. Second, the only use of reflection here is to save you the trouble of passing both value selector and similar headers. I think this code is just fine when hidden inside a black box library, LINQ implementation uses similar atrocities.

Anyhow, I'm glad to see that even after I've left .NET this code is still alive. It's almost 9 years old!

Answer (score 23):

```
class ArrayPrinter
    {
    #region Declarations

    static bool isLeftAligned = false;
    const string cellLeftTop = "┌";
    const string cellRightTop = "┐";
    const string cellLeftBottom = "└";
    const string cellRightBottom = "┘";
    const string cellHorizontalJointTop = "┬";
    const string cellHorizontalJointbottom = "┴";
    const string cellVerticalJointLeft = "├";
    const string cellTJoint = "┼";
    const string cellVerticalJointRight = "┤";
    const string cellHorizontalLine = "─";
    const string cellVerticalLine = "│";

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private static int GetMaxCellWidth(string[,] arrValues)
    {
        int maxWidth = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrValues.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrValues.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                int length = arrValues[i, j].Length;
                if (length > maxWidth)
                {
                    maxWidth = length;
                }
            }
        }

        return maxWidth;
    }

    private static string GetDataInTableFormat(string[,] arrValues)
    {
        string formattedString = string.Empty;

        if (arrValues == null)
            return formattedString;

        int dimension1Length = arrValues.GetLength(0);
        int dimension2Length = arrValues.GetLength(1);

        int maxCellWidth = GetMaxCellWidth(arrValues);
        int indentLength = (dimension2Length * maxCellWidth) + (dimension2Length - 1);
        //printing top line;
        formattedString = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", cellLeftTop, Indent(indentLength), cellRightTop, System.Environment.NewLine);

        for (int i = 0; i < dimension1Length; i++)
        {
            string lineWithValues = cellVerticalLine;
            string line = cellVerticalJointLeft;
            for (int j = 0; j < dimension2Length; j++)
            {
                string value = (isLeftAligned) ? arrValues[i, j].PadRight(maxCellWidth, ' ') : arrValues[i, j].PadLeft(maxCellWidth, ' ');
                lineWithValues += string.Format("{0}{1}", value, cellVerticalLine);
                line += Indent(maxCellWidth);
                if (j < (dimension2Length - 1))
                {
                    line += cellTJoint;
                }
            }
            line += cellVerticalJointRight;
            formattedString += string.Format("{0}{1}", lineWithValues, System.Environment.NewLine);
            if (i < (dimension1Length - 1))
            {
                formattedString += string.Format("{0}{1}", line, System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        //printing bottom line
        formattedString += string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", cellLeftBottom, Indent(indentLength), cellRightBottom, System.Environment.NewLine);
        return formattedString;
    }

    private static string Indent(int count)
    {
        return string.Empty.PadLeft(count, '─');                 
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public static void PrintToStream(string[,] arrValues, StreamWriter writer)
    {
        if (arrValues == null)
            return;

        if (writer == null)
            return;

        writer.Write(GetDataInTableFormat(arrValues));
    }

    public static void PrintToConsole(string[,] arrValues)
    {
        if (arrValues == null)
            return;

        Console.WriteLine(GetDataInTableFormat(arrValues));
    }

    #endregion

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        int value = 997;
        string[,] arrValues = new string[5, 5];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrValues.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrValues.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                value++;
                arrValues[i, j] = value.ToString();
            }
        }
        ArrayPrinter.PrintToConsole(arrValues);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: For more flexibility and better code reuse: 1. change parameter type from `StreamWriter` to `TextWriter`. 2. Replace `PrintToConsole` code with: `PrintToStream(arrValues, Console.Out);` 3. ??? 4. PROFIT!

Answer (score 17):

I wanted variable-width columns, and I didn't particularly care about the box characters.  Also, I needed to print some extra information for each row.

So in case anyone else needs that, I'll save you few minutes:

```
public class TestTableBuilder
{

    public interface ITextRow
    {
        String Output();
        void Output(StringBuilder sb);
        Object Tag { get; set; }
    }

    public class TableBuilder : IEnumerable<ITextRow>
    {
        protected class TextRow : List<String>, ITextRow
        {
            protected TableBuilder owner = null;
            public TextRow(TableBuilder Owner)
            {
                owner = Owner;
                if (owner == null) throw new ArgumentException("Owner");
            }
            public String Output()
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Output(sb);
                return sb.ToString();
            }
            public void Output(StringBuilder sb)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat(owner.FormatString, this.ToArray());
            }
            public Object Tag { get; set; }
        }

        public String Separator { get; set; }

        protected List<ITextRow> rows = new List<ITextRow>();
        protected List<int> colLength = new List<int>();

        public TableBuilder()
        {
            Separator = "  ";
        }

        public TableBuilder(String separator)
            : this()
        {
            Separator = separator;
        }

        public ITextRow AddRow(params object[] cols)
        {
            TextRow row = new TextRow(this);
            foreach (object o in cols)
            {
                String str = o.ToString().Trim();
                row.Add(str);
                if (colLength.Count >= row.Count)
                {
                    int curLength = colLength[row.Count - 1];
                    if (str.Length > curLength) colLength[row.Count - 1] = str.Length;
                }
                else
                {
                    colLength.Add(str.Length);
                }
            }
            rows.Add(row);
            return row;
        }

        protected String _fmtString = null;
        public String FormatString
        {
            get
            {
                if (_fmtString == null)
                {
                    String format = "";
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (int len in colLength)
                    {
                        format += String.Format("{{{0},-{1}}}{2}", i++, len, Separator);
                    }
                    format += "\r\n";
                    _fmtString = format;
                }
                return _fmtString;
            }
        }

        public String Output()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (TextRow row in rows)
            {
                row.Output(sb);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        #region IEnumerable Members

        public IEnumerator<ITextRow> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return rows.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return rows.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }



    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        TableBuilder tb = new TableBuilder();
        tb.AddRow("When", "ID", "Name");
        tb.AddRow("----", "--", "----");

        tb.AddRow(DateTime.Now, "1", "Name1");
        tb.AddRow(DateTime.Now, "1", "Name2");

        Console.Write(tb.Output());
        Console.WriteLine();

        // or

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (ITextRow tr in tb)
        {
            tr.Output(sb);
            if (i++ > 1) sb.AppendLine("more stuff per line");
        }
        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
When                 ID  Name
----                 --  ----
2/4/2013 8:37:44 PM  1   Name1
2/4/2013 8:37:44 PM  1   Name2

When                 ID  Name
----                 --  ----
2/4/2013 8:37:44 PM  1   Name1
more stuff per line
2/4/2013 8:37:44 PM  1   Name2
more stuff per line
```

Answer (score 16):

I have a project on GitHub that you can use

https://github.com/BrunoVT1992/ConsoleTable

You can use it like this:

```
var table = new Table();

table.SetHeaders("Name", "Date", "Number");

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        table.AddRow($"name {i}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToLongDateString(), i.ToString());
    else
        table.AddRow($"long name {i}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToLongDateString(), (i * 5000).ToString());
}

Console.WriteLine(table.ToString());
```

It will give this result:

[image]

Comment: There exists other packages than yours for this, but I like yours better because the output is nicer with special characters for the line junctions. The API is simple and doesn't assume too much (such as requiring headers), which is nice. Would you consider adding it on Nuget? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Nice @BrunoVT. Thanks! And I'd like a Nuget as well.

Comment: This one is my preferred choice, simple, good looking and gets the job done. Thanks.

Comment: Great job. Tried it and looks good.

Answer (score 14):

In case if this helps someone, this is a simple class I wrote for my need. You can change it easily to fit your needs.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Utilities
{
    public class TablePrinter
    {
        private readonly string[] titles;
        private readonly List<int> lengths;
        private readonly List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]>();

        public TablePrinter(params string[] titles)
        {
            this.titles = titles;
            lengths = titles.Select(t => t.Length).ToList();
        }

        public void AddRow(params object[] row)
        {
            if (row.Length != titles.Length)
            {
                throw new System.Exception($"Added row length [{row.Length}] is not equal to title row length [{titles.Length}]");
            }
            rows.Add(row.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray());
            for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
            {
                if (rows.Last()[i].Length > lengths[i])
                {
                    lengths[i] = rows.Last()[i].Length;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            lengths.ForEach(l => System.Console.Write("+-" + new string('-', l) + '-'));
            System.Console.WriteLine("+");

            string line = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
            {
                line += "| " + titles[i].PadRight(lengths[i]) + ' ';
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(line + "|");

            lengths.ForEach(l => System.Console.Write("+-" + new string('-', l) + '-'));
            System.Console.WriteLine("+");

            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                line = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(row[i], out int n))
                    {
                        line += "| " + row[i].PadLeft(lengths[i]) + ' ';  // numbers are padded to the left
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line += "| " + row[i].PadRight(lengths[i]) + ' ';
                    }
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine(line + "|");
            }

            lengths.ForEach(l => System.Console.Write("+-" + new string('-', l) + '-'));
            System.Console.WriteLine("+");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var t = new TablePrinter("id", "Column A", "Column B");
t.AddRow(1, "Val A1", "Val B1");
t.AddRow(2, "Val A2", "Val B2");
t.AddRow(100, "Val A100", "Val B100");
t.Print();
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------+----------+
| id  | Column A | Column B |
+-----+----------+----------+
|   1 | Val A1   | Val B1   |
|   2 | Val A2   | Val B2   |
| 100 | Val A100 | Val B100 |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 14):

[Spectre.Console](https://github.com/spectreconsole/spectre.console) can do this.

Example:

[image: Tables are a perfect way of displaying tabular data in a terminal.]

Simple usage:

```
// Create a table
var table = new Table();

// Add some columns
table.AddColumn("Foo");
table.AddColumn(new TableColumn("Bar").Centered());

// Add some rows
table.AddRow("Baz", "[green]Qux[/]");
table.AddRow(new Markup("[blue]Corgi[/]"), new Panel("Waldo"));

// Render the table to the console
AnsiConsole.Render(table);
```

Comment: And Spectre also has a Live-Update functionality.
See https://spectreconsole.net/live/live-display for details.

Answer (score 11):

This is an improvement to a previous answer.  It adds support for values with varying lengths and rows with a varying number of cells.  For example:

```
┌──────────┬─────────┬──────────────────────────┬────────────────┬─────┬───────┐
│Identifier│     Type│               Description│  CPU Credit Use│Hours│Balance│
├──────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────┼────────────────┼─────┼───────┘
│ i-1234154│ t2.small│       This is an example.│         3263.75│  360│
├──────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────┼────────────────┼─────┘
│ i-1231412│ t2.small│  This is another example.│         3089.93│
└──────────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Here is the code:

```
public class ArrayPrinter
{
    const string TOP_LEFT_JOINT = "┌";
    const string TOP_RIGHT_JOINT = "┐";
    const string BOTTOM_LEFT_JOINT = "└";
    const string BOTTOM_RIGHT_JOINT = "┘";
    const string TOP_JOINT = "┬";
    const string BOTTOM_JOINT = "┴";
    const string LEFT_JOINT = "├";
    const string JOINT = "┼";
    const string RIGHT_JOINT = "┤";
    const char HORIZONTAL_LINE = '─';
    const char PADDING = ' ';
    const string VERTICAL_LINE = "│";

    private static int[] GetMaxCellWidths(List<string[]> table)
    {
        int maximumCells = 0;
        foreach (Array row in table)
        {
            if (row.Length > maximumCells)
                maximumCells = row.Length;
        }

        int[] maximumCellWidths = new int[maximumCells];
        for (int i = 0; i < maximumCellWidths.Length; i++)
            maximumCellWidths[i] = 0;

        foreach (Array row in table)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
            {
                if (row.GetValue(i).ToString().Length > maximumCellWidths[i])
                    maximumCellWidths[i] = row.GetValue(i).ToString().Length;
            }
        }

        return maximumCellWidths;
    }

    public static string GetDataInTableFormat(List<string[]> table)
    {
        StringBuilder formattedTable = new StringBuilder();
        Array nextRow = table.FirstOrDefault();
        Array previousRow = table.FirstOrDefault();

        if (table == null || nextRow == null)
            return String.Empty;

        // FIRST LINE:
        int[] maximumCellWidths = GetMaxCellWidths(table);
        for (int i = 0; i < nextRow.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && i == nextRow.Length - 1)
                formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", TOP_LEFT_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), TOP_RIGHT_JOINT));
            else if (i == 0)
                formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", TOP_LEFT_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
            else if (i == nextRow.Length - 1)
                formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", TOP_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), TOP_RIGHT_JOINT));
            else
                formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", TOP_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
        }

        int rowIndex = 0;
        int lastRowIndex = table.Count - 1;
        foreach (Array thisRow in table)
        {
            // LINE WITH VALUES:
            int cellIndex = 0;
            int lastCellIndex = thisRow.Length - 1;
            foreach (object thisCell in thisRow)
            {
                string thisValue = thisCell.ToString().PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[cellIndex], PADDING);

                if (cellIndex == 0 && cellIndex == lastCellIndex)
                    formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", VERTICAL_LINE, thisValue, VERTICAL_LINE));
                else if (cellIndex == 0)
                    formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", VERTICAL_LINE, thisValue));
                else if (cellIndex == lastCellIndex)
                    formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", VERTICAL_LINE, thisValue, VERTICAL_LINE));
                else
                    formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", VERTICAL_LINE, thisValue));

                cellIndex++;
            }

            previousRow = thisRow;

            // SEPARATING LINE:
            if (rowIndex != lastRowIndex)
            {
                nextRow = table[rowIndex + 1];

                int maximumCells = Math.Max(previousRow.Length, nextRow.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < maximumCells; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 && i == maximumCells - 1)
                    {
                        formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", LEFT_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), RIGHT_JOINT));
                    }
                    else if (i == 0)
                    {
                        formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", LEFT_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
                    }
                    else if (i == maximumCells - 1)
                    {
                        if (i > previousRow.Length)
                            formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", TOP_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), TOP_RIGHT_JOINT));
                        else if (i > nextRow.Length)
                            formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", BOTTOM_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), BOTTOM_RIGHT_JOINT));
                        else if (i > previousRow.Length - 1)
                            formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), TOP_RIGHT_JOINT));
                        else if (i > nextRow.Length - 1)
                            formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), BOTTOM_RIGHT_JOINT));
                        else
                            formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), RIGHT_JOINT));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i > previousRow.Length)
                            formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", TOP_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
                        else if (i > nextRow.Length)
                            formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", BOTTOM_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
                        else
                            formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
                    }
                }
            }

            rowIndex++;
        }

        // LAST LINE:
        for (int i = 0; i < previousRow.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", BOTTOM_LEFT_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
            else if (i == previousRow.Length - 1)
                formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", BOTTOM_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), BOTTOM_RIGHT_JOINT));
            else
                formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", BOTTOM_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
        }

        return formattedTable.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it appeared after some testing your code does not handle well the case of a single column.

Answer (score 5):

Use MarkDownLog library (you can find it on NuGet)

you can simply use the extension ToMarkdownTable() to any collection, it does all the formatting for you.

```
 Console.WriteLine(
    yourCollection.Select(s => new
                    {
                        column1 = s.col1,
                        column2 = s.col2,
                        column3 = s.col3,
                        StaticColumn = "X"
                    })
                    .ToMarkdownTable());
```

Output looks something like this:

```
Column1  | Column2   | Column3   | StaticColumn   
--------:| ---------:| ---------:| --------------
         |           |           | X
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void ToPrintConsole(this DataTable dataTable)
    {
        // Print top line
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 75));

        // Print col headers
        var colHeaders = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(arg => arg.ColumnName);
        foreach (String s in colHeaders)
        {
            Console.Write("| {0,-20}", s);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Print line below col headers
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 75));

        // Print rows
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (Object o in row.ItemArray)
            {
                Console.Write("| {0,-20}", o.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // Print bottom line
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 75));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use string interpolation by adding `$`, like following example:

```
$"|{arg0,5}|{arg1,5}|{arg2,5}|{arg3,5}|";
```

Put that in a simple example:

```
----------------------------------
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
----------------------------------
|Left11    |        12|        13|
|Left21    |        22|        23|
|Left31    |        32|        33|
|Left41    |        42|        43|
```

Here is the code:

```
var list = new List<Data>()
{
    new() {S1 = "Left11", S2 = "12", S3 = "13"},
    new() {S1 = "Left21", S2 = "22", S3 = "23"},
    new() {S1 = "Left31", S2 = "32", S3 = "33"},
    new() {S1 = "Left41", S2 = "42", S3 = "43"}
};

var lineSep = "----------------------------------";
var header = $"|{" Column 1 ",10}|{" Column 2 ",10}|{" Column 3 ",10}|";
Console.WriteLine(lineSep);
Console.WriteLine(header);
Console.WriteLine(lineSep);

foreach (var data in list)
{
    var line = $"|{data.S1,-10}|{data.S2,10}|{data.S3,10}|";
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}


class Data
{
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I offer my choice:

https://github.com/Grizzly-pride/Console_Menu_Tools.git

```
MenuBuilder menuTable = new(1, 60, 3, 1, true)
{    ItemsMenu = new()
     {
          myTable.AddTopLine(),
          myTable.AddHeader(),
          myTable.AddMiddleLine(),
          myTable.AddRow("The Witcher 3", "action/RPG", "05.02.2013"),
          myTable.AddRow("Diablo 2", "RPG", "05.07.2002"),
          myTable.AddRow("Warcraft 3", "TBS", "29.06.2000"),
          myTable.AddRow("Quake 2", "Shooter", "18.02.1997"),
          myTable.AddRow("Grand Theft Auto: Vice City", "action-adventure", 
          "27.10.2002"),
          myTable.AddEndLine(),
     },
     PointerColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow,
     ItemColor = ConsoleColor.Green
 };

 menuTable.SetCursorVisible(false);
 int selectRow = menuTable.RunMenu();

 Console.WriteLine($"\n\n -> Selected: {selectRow}");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbZHE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Extension to @grampa answer. Now table is centered aligned. with extra padding added from both end.

```
public class TablePrinter
{
    const string TOP_LEFT_JOINT = "┌";
    const string TOP_RIGHT_JOINT = "┐";
    const string BOTTOM_LEFT_JOINT = "└";
    const string BOTTOM_RIGHT_JOINT = "┘";
    const string TOP_JOINT = "┬";
    const string BOTTOM_JOINT = "┴";
    const string LEFT_JOINT = "├";
    const string JOINT = "┼";
    const string RIGHT_JOINT = "┤";
    const char HORIZONTAL_LINE = '─';
    const char PADDING = ' ';
    const string VERTICAL_LINE = "│";

    private static int[] GetMaxCellWidths(List<string[]> table)
    {
        int maximumCells = 0;
        foreach (Array row in table)
        {
            if (row.Length > maximumCells)
                maximumCells = row.Length;
        }

        int[] maximumCellWidths = new int[maximumCells];
        for (int i = 0; i < maximumCellWidths.Length; i++)
            maximumCellWidths[i] = 0;

        foreach (Array row in table)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
            {
                if (row.GetValue(i).ToString().Length > maximumCellWidths[i])
                    maximumCellWidths[i] = row.GetValue(i).ToString().Length +2;
            }
        }

        return maximumCellWidths;
    }

    public static string GetDataInTableFormat(List<string[]> table)
    {
        StringBuilder formattedTable = new StringBuilder();
        Array nextRow = table.FirstOrDefault();
        Array previousRow = table.FirstOrDefault();

        if (table == null || nextRow == null)
            return String.Empty;

        // FIRST LINE:
        int[] maximumCellWidths = GetMaxCellWidths(table);
        for (int i = 0; i < nextRow.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && i == nextRow.Length - 1)
                formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", TOP_LEFT_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), TOP_RIGHT_JOINT));
            else if (i == 0)
                formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", TOP_LEFT_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
            else if (i == nextRow.Length - 1)
                formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", TOP_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), TOP_RIGHT_JOINT));
            else
                formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", TOP_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
        }

        int rowIndex = 0;
        int lastRowIndex = table.Count - 1;
        foreach (Array thisRow in table)
        {
            // LINE WITH VALUES:
            int cellIndex = 0;
            int lastCellIndex = thisRow.Length - 1;
            foreach (object thisCell in thisRow)
            {
                string thisValue = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", String.Empty.PadLeft((maximumCellWidths[cellIndex] - thisCell.ToString().Length)/ 2),thisCell.ToString(),String.Empty.PadRight(((maximumCellWidths[cellIndex] - thisCell.ToString().Length + 1) / 2)));

                if (cellIndex == 0 && cellIndex == lastCellIndex)
                    formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", VERTICAL_LINE, thisValue, VERTICAL_LINE));
                else if (cellIndex == 0)
                    formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", VERTICAL_LINE, thisValue));
                else if (cellIndex == lastCellIndex)
                    formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", VERTICAL_LINE, thisValue, VERTICAL_LINE));
                else
                    formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", VERTICAL_LINE, thisValue));

                cellIndex++;
            }

            previousRow = thisRow;

            // SEPARATING LINE:
            if (rowIndex != lastRowIndex)
            {
                nextRow = table[rowIndex + 1];

                int maximumCells = Math.Max(previousRow.Length, nextRow.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < maximumCells; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 && i == maximumCells - 1)
                    {
                        formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", LEFT_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), RIGHT_JOINT));
                    }
                    else if (i == 0)
                    {
                        formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", LEFT_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
                    }
                    else if (i == maximumCells - 1)
                    {
                        if (i > previousRow.Length)
                            formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", TOP_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), TOP_RIGHT_JOINT));
                        else if (i > nextRow.Length)
                            formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", BOTTOM_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), BOTTOM_RIGHT_JOINT));
                        else if (i > previousRow.Length - 1)
                            formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), TOP_RIGHT_JOINT));
                        else if (i > nextRow.Length - 1)
                            formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight((maximumCellWidths[i]), HORIZONTAL_LINE), BOTTOM_RIGHT_JOINT));
                        else
                            formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight((maximumCellWidths[i]), HORIZONTAL_LINE), RIGHT_JOINT));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i > previousRow.Length)
                            formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", TOP_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
                        else if (i > nextRow.Length)
                            formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", BOTTOM_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
                        else
                            formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE).PadRight(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
                    }
                }
            }

            rowIndex++;
        }

        // LAST LINE:
        for (int i = 0; i < previousRow.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", BOTTOM_LEFT_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
            else if (i == previousRow.Length - 1)
                formattedTable.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", BOTTOM_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE), BOTTOM_RIGHT_JOINT));
            else
                formattedTable.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", BOTTOM_JOINT, String.Empty.PadLeft(maximumCellWidths[i], HORIZONTAL_LINE)));
        }

        return formattedTable.ToString();
    }
}
```

Output is well formatted and looking so beautiful

```
┌─────────┬───────────┬───────────┬────────────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ Root Id │ HotelRate │ percentan │ RightValue │ Occupied │ Closed │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────┼────────┤
│  3034   │    100    │ 40.816306 │     15     │    -0    │   -0   │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────┼────────┤
│  3035   │    100    │ 16.666666 │     0      │    -0    │   45   │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────┼────────┤
│  3036   │    100    │ 44.44444  │     0      │    -0    │   30   │
└─────────┴───────────┴───────────┴────────────┴──────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: next time highlight your output section and click the Code Sample "{ }" Icon on your text editor.

Comment: @Demodave Thanks, I was struggling with this formatted output and could not succeed. You made it right.

Answer (score -7):

It's easier in VisualBasic.net!

If you want the user to be able to manually enter data into a table:

```
Console.Write("Enter Data For Column 1: ")
    Dim Data1 As String = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Enter Data For Column 2: ")
    Dim Data2 As String = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-10} {2,-10}", "{Data Type}", "{Column 1}", "{Column 2}")
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-10} {2,-10}", "Data Entered:", Data1, Data2)

    Console.WriteLine("ENTER To Exit: ")
    Console.ReadLine()
```

It should look like this:

[image: It should look like this (Click Me).]

Comment: I thought this was useful because all I wanted was simple column alignment in C#, and Console.WriteLine() works similarly in both languages.