# Pivot the table result using linq c#

Tags: c#

want to Pivot this table using linq c#

[My Table is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2CqC.png)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code conversion tool!

Comment: So, what have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: hope so you got my table result , i just want to pivot it using linq c#

Comment: could you explain what you want to achieve? please, be more specific

Comment: So exactly what is the problem you are having with the code you have written so far? If you show that code then maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question does not provide what to pivot by.. I did a pivot to count on a period of 50. Change it to your preference. Check this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KhB603).

```
var result = myList
            .GroupBy(x => x.Branch)
            .Select(y => new {
                           Branch = y.Key, 
                           FirstPeriod = y.Count(z => z.Quantity > 100 && z.Quantity <= 150), 
                           SecondPeriod = y.Count(z => z.Quantity > 150 && z.Quantity <= 200), 
                           ThirdPeriod = y.Count(z => z.Quantity > 200 && z.Quantity <= 250)
                        }).ToList();
```

References:

[Excellent Pivot Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/167937/4201229)

[Method used in the fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114190/4201229)

Comment: Thanks for your time ... I was looking for dynamic column and finally i got the solution... Once again thank You for your time and efforts...