# formatting output data neatly C++

Tags: c++

When I print the results of my program to the screen, the data is all over the place but I want to align the results as best as possible. I am using setw(10) in order to do this but it's not working properly can someone help me?

Thanks

This is what the output looks like:

[image]

This is my print function:

```
void Print(const call_record *call_DB, int & count)
{

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    for(int i= 0; i <= count; i++)
    {
        cout << call_DB[i].firstname <<" " << call_DB[i].lastname <<"  "  << call_DB[i].cell_number <<setw(15) << call_DB[i].relays <<setw(10) << call_DB[i].call_length;
        cout <<setw(10) << call_DB[i].net_cost <<setw(10) << call_DB[i].call_rate << setw(10) << call_DB[i].call_tax <<setw(10) << call_DB[i].total_cost;

        cout << endl;


    }
}
```

Comment: You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755250/format-output-in-a-table-c).

Answer (score 1):

You must, of course, also set the width of the output of the strings (or of the combined name):

```
cout << std::setw(20) << (call_DB[i].firstname + call_DB[i].lastname);
```

(assuming that these are `std::string`s such that `+` concatenates them).

Answer (score 1):

One of the best practices I have known on C++ output is using template functions.

**Sample**:

Your template function:

```
template<typename T> void coutElement(T t, const int& width)
{
    cout << std::left << setw(width) << setfill(separator) << t;
}
```

---

Using it:

```
const int name_width = 10; //non sense value
const int num_width  = 10; //non sense value
coutElement("Dainer", name_width);
coutElement("Doe", name_width);
coutElement(250, num_width);
```

This has always worked flawlessly, the only challenging thing about it is the decision you'll take for the values of `name_width` and `num_width`

Comment: what is `left`?

Comment: sorry my bad, I didn't edit the code I copied from my project. Thanks.

Comment: i assume its std::left

Comment: I just revised my code, left is std::left