# Draw a timetable in console out of 3D-Array

Tags: c#

I want to draw  a timetable in console application:

```
---------------------------------------------------
 |    Mo     |    Tu     |    We     |    ...     |
---------------------------------------------------
1| Math      |           |           |            |
 | Teacher   |           |           |            |
 | Room      |           |           |            |
---------------------------------------------------
2| ...
```

I guess it's an 3D-Array. Dimension 1 is x, dimension 2 is y and dimension 3 is an object called "lesson".
The properties of the lesson-objects are topic, teacher, room and others (begin, end, ...)

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |    Mo           |    Tu     |    We     |    ...     |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Math            |           |           |            |
 | Teacher         |           |           |            |
 | Room            |           |           |            |
 | Begin: 2012.1.1 |           |           |            |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The appearance should automatically fit rows, width and so on.

A really cool solution can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856918/1208574)

But the solution is only 2D. I did some investigation, but cannot fill in complete object.

Comment: I see only 2D `o_O` this table has no depth or anything alike whatsoever...

Comment: can you show us a sample of this "3D Array"?

Comment: I think 3d means that each row contains different information, like topic, teacher, etc..

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: It' s like ramsesoriginal said. I thought the depth is, that in one cell may appear more than one value...

Answer (score 1):

This is not the prettiest or most elegant solution, nor the most efficient one, but it works.

Assuming that a lesson looks somewhat like this:

```
      class Lesson
      {
          public string topic = "math";
          public string teacher = "mandelbrot";
          public string room = "E215";
          public string begin = "08:00";
          public string end = "09:00";

          public Lesson()
              : this(null, null, null, null, null)
          {
          }

          public Lesson(string t)
              : this(t, null, null, null, null)
          {
          }


          public Lesson(string t, string t2)
              : this(t, t2, null, null, null)
          {
          }


          public Lesson(string t, string t2, string r)
              : this(t, t2, r, null, null)
          {
          }


          public Lesson(string t, string t2, string r, string b)
              : this(t, t2, r, b, null)
          {
          }
          public Lesson(string t, string t2, string r, string b, string e)
          {
              topic = t??"math";
              teacher = t2??"mandelbrot";
              room = r??"E215";
              begin = b??"08:00";
              end = e??"09:00";

          }

      }
```

I created a class that converts a `Lesson[][]` array to a pretty formatted string:

```
      class OutPutter
      {
          private static int[] maxlength = new int[7];
          public static Lesson[][] timetable = new Lesson[7][];

          public OutPutter()
              : this(null)
          {
          }

          public OutPutter(Lesson[][] tt)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
              {
                  maxlength[i] = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames.ElementAt(i).Length;
                  timetable[i] = ((tt == null || tt[i] == null) ? new Lesson[24] : tt[i]);
              } 
          }


          public void add(int day, int hour, Lesson lesson)
          {
              day -= 1;
              timetable[day][hour]=lesson;
              int currentLongest = maxlength[day];
              if (lesson.begin.Length > currentLongest)
                  currentLongest = lesson.begin.Length;
              if (lesson.end.Length > currentLongest)
                  currentLongest = lesson.end.Length;
              if (lesson.teacher.Length > currentLongest)
                  currentLongest = lesson.teacher.Length;
              if (lesson.topic.Length > currentLongest)
                  currentLongest = lesson.topic.Length;
              if (lesson.room.Length > currentLongest)
                  currentLongest = lesson.room.Length;
              if (currentLongest != maxlength[day])
                  maxlength[day] = currentLongest;
          }

          private static Lesson getLesson(int i2, int i)
          {
              try 
              {
                  return timetable[i][i2] ?? new Lesson("", "", "", "", "");
              }
              catch 
              {
                  return new Lesson("", "", "", "", "");
              }
          }

          public override string ToString()
          {
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              int maxLessons = 0;
              foreach (Lesson[] current in timetable)
              {
                  if (current.Length > maxLessons)
                      maxLessons = current.Length;
              }
              int lineLength = 1;
              List<string> formatstrings = new List<string>();
              for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
              {
                  formatstrings.Add(" {0,"+maxlength[i].ToString()+"}");
                  sb.Append("|");
                  sb.AppendFormat(formatstrings.ElementAt(i), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames.ElementAt(i));
                  lineLength += maxlength[i] + 2;
              }
              sb.Append("|");
              sb.AppendLine();
              sb.Append("".PadLeft(lineLength, '='));
              for (int i2 = 0; i2 < maxLessons; i2++)
              {
                  sb.AppendLine();
                  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                  {
                      sb.Append("|");
                      sb.AppendFormat(formatstrings.ElementAt(i), getLesson(i2, i).topic);
                  }
                  sb.Append("|");
                  sb.AppendLine();
                  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                  {
                      sb.Append("|");
                      sb.AppendFormat(formatstrings.ElementAt(i), getLesson(i2, i).teacher);
                  }
                  sb.Append("|");
                  sb.AppendLine();
                  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                  {
                      sb.Append("|");
                      sb.AppendFormat(formatstrings.ElementAt(i), getLesson(i2, i).room);
                  }
                  sb.Append("|");
                  sb.AppendLine();
                  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                  {
                      sb.Append("|");
                      sb.AppendFormat(formatstrings.ElementAt(i), getLesson(i2, i).begin);
                  }
                  sb.Append("|");
                  sb.AppendLine();
                  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                  {
                      sb.Append("|");
                      sb.AppendFormat(formatstrings.ElementAt(i), getLesson(i2, i).end);
                  }
                  sb.Append("|");
                  sb.AppendLine();
                  sb.Append("".PadLeft(lineLength, '-'));
              }
              return sb.ToString();
          }

      }
```

A sample usage:

```
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              OutPutter op = new OutPutter();
              op.add(1,1, new Lesson());
              op.add(1,3, new Lesson("Analysis"));
              op.add(2,5, new Lesson());
              op.add(3,0, new Lesson());
              op.add(5,7, new Lesson("CompSci", "A. S. Tann."));
              Console.Write(op.ToString());
              Console.Read();
          }
      }
```

Like I said, this is **just a quick and dirty solution**, just to give you some ideas on how this could be achieved. It's definitively not clean or optimal, so you should refactor it. **A lot**. But as an example it should work.

**EDIT**

And here's the output this would produce:

```
 |     Sunday|     Monday|    Tuesday| Wednesday|    Thursday| Friday| Saturday|
 ===============================================================================
 |           |           |       math|          |            |       |         |
 |           |           | mandelbrot|          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |       E215|          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |      08:00|          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |      09:00|          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |       math|           |           |          |            |       |         |
 | mandelbrot|           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |       E215|           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |      08:00|           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |      09:00|           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   Analysis|           |           |          |            |       |         |
 | mandelbrot|           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |       E215|           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |      08:00|           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |      09:00|           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |       math|           |          |            |       |         |
 |           | mandelbrot|           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |       E215|           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |      08:00|           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |      09:00|           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |     CompSci|       |         |
 |           |           |           |          | A. S. Tann.|       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |        E215|       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |       08:00|       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |       09:00|       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 |           |           |           |          |            |       |         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```