# How do I align text in an array in a table view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, tableview

I'm new to Objective-C coding. However, my problem is very straightforward if you take a look at the image below of my output. Basically I want everything to be aligned correctly such that all the data in the rows look like they are in their own columns. Basically each row should be aligned with the row above it. My program is bringing in each field from a JSON file from the web - please also see code to see how I'm doing it.

[image]

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData    options:0 error:nil];



    for (NSDictionary *diction in allDataDictionary) {
        NSString *currDate = [diction objectForKey:@"Current Date"];
        NSString *timePeriod = [diction objectForKey:@"Time Period"];
        NSString *transCount = [diction objectForKey:@"Transaction Processed"];
        NSString *approved = [diction objectForKey:@"Approved"];
        NSString *posApproved = [diction objectForKey:@"Standing App"];
        NSString *approvalRate = [diction objectForKey:@"Approval Rate"];
        NSString *respTime = [diction objectForKey:@"Resp Time"];

        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@       %@       %@       %@       %@       %@", timePeriod, transCount, approved, posApproved, approvalRate, respTime]];



    } [[self myTableView] reloadData];
```

My Table View:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

   // NSString *currDate = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Current Date"]; //added
   //  NSString *someOtherKey = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Some other key"]; //added


    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   // cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@", currDate, someOtherKey]; //added

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see other way rather than HTML solution.

Simply create NSString with table and show it in UIWebView.

E.g.

```
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<table><tr>"
                                                    "<td>%@</td>"
                                                    "</tr></table>",
                                                    JSON_VARIABLE];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blank spaces here:

```
array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@       %@       %@       %@       %@       %@", timePeriod, transCount, approved, posApproved, approvalRate, respTime]];
```

You can use tabulator "\t", something like:

```
array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \t %@ \t %@ \t %@ \t %@ \t %@", timePeriod, transCount, approved, posApproved, approvalRate, respTime]];
```

Comment: That's good to know, thank you. Do you have any advice on how I can align everything?

Comment: Use \t to separate each of the elements and it should align the text if the length of text are some how similar, otherwise you could use two tab instead.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work because each element could have different number of digits as they come in

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856845/how-to-best-way-to-draw-table-in-console-app-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can decide a standard length that every string will have and fill the extra space needed with spaces characters.If you choose the maximum length between all strings, then no string will be cut:

```
NSString* formatted=[yourString stringByPaddingToLength: maxLength withString: @" " startingAtIndex: 0];
```

Comment: I'm not sure where this will go and how to implement it