# Displaying array elements next to each other in a field?

Tags: c#

How do I arrange the numbers next to each other instead of on top of each other?

I tried implementing \t but it gives me an error or doesn't do anything at all.

```
 int[] anzFeldElemente = new int[10];
        Random wuerfel = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < anzFeldElemente.Length; i++)
        {
            anzFeldElemente[i] = wuerfel.Next(0, 100);
        }

        Array.Sort(anzFeldElemente);

        foreach (int i in anzFeldElemente)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i "\t");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Also, is it possible to draw a field similar to Microsoft Excel in a console app? Is there a function to draw one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: What you mean with a field similar to Excel? a cell?

Comment: That doesn't help, because I get something like this instead: 1234124152841. I wanted to use \t because it'll show me the 10 numbers separately.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade Yes, but more cells, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Brafolf use console.write(i + " ")

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To: Best way to draw table in console app (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856845/how-to-best-way-to-draw-table-in-console-app-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name implies, `Console.WriteLine` writes a line.

Instead of

```
Console.WriteLine(i "\t");
```

Try

```
Console.Write(i + "\t");
```

Or

```
Console.Write("{0}\t", i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Console.WriteLine will force it to move to the next line every time you iterate. As recommended by lazyberezovsky use the Console.Write instead. Remember to include a white space to divide up the elements using +", "

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
Console.Write(i + "\t");
```