# Group by and Count result in LinQ

Tags: linq

I have 1 very basic table which I need to query in order to get the amount (count) of rooms in each building code using a LinQ query.

So far i have this:

```
var myQuery = 
    from s in Locations 
    group  s.Room by s.BldgCode into t
    select t.Count();

        myQuery.Dump();
```

with this output

```
Query (3 items)
2
4
7
```

How can I include the Building code details so I have an output like this:

```
BldgCode    NoRooms (3 items)
   A           2
   B           4
   C           7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(var line in data.GroupBy(info => info.Room )
                        .Select(group => new { 
                             BldgCode = group.Key, 
                             NoRooms = group.Count() 
                        })
                        {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", line.BldgCode , line.NoRooms );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works however is there a way to display the table neatly with headers using LINQPad4 other than the WriteLine function...

Comment: u mean you want to display table in console?

Comment: yes, sorry I know its basic but I just cant seem to get it right

Comment: don't say sorry even I am a learner :) this links might be useful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856845/how-to-best-way-to-draw-table-in-console-app-c, http://tech.pro/tutorial/1267/displaying-tables-in-a-c-console