# c# string formatting for printing

Tags: c#, string

I saw somewhere on this board where someone created a string to print that held multiple variables that you could print a form.  I can find the original question but would like to use the way the string was constructed.

I want to have the string like hold something like this.

```
string("|", {size of field1}, "|", {size of field2}, "|", {size of field3}, "|"), field1, field2, field3);
```

I want the size for each field to be constant so it makes a nice table.

Comment: You might want to google "format string in c#" before posting a question here.

Comment: Seriously, it's the first result...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To: Best way to draw table in console app (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856845/how-to-best-way-to-draw-table-in-console-app-c)

Comment: ...so the first thing you mention in your question is that you know it has already been answered on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string formattedString = String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", field1, field2, field3);
```

Alternatively if you're not sure how many strings to combine you will have you can use the Join method.

```
string formattedString = String.Join("|", stringsToJoin);
```

In this case stringsToJoin should be an array.