# Output table with foreach and format it nice

Tags: c#, list, console-application

I want to output the results of my program in a nice looking table. With table I mean the files listed among themselves then a tabulator and the score listed among themselves. How can I achieve that this works so? At the moment my program is able to print out ONE file at a time but ALL other scores among themselves. The result should look like this:

```
file1 score1
file2 score2
file3 score3
```

But at the moment it looks like this:

```
file1 score1 
score2 
score3
file2 score1
score2
score3
```

I think the 2nd `foreach` is wrong but how can I output one element of a list without `for/foreach`?

Thats my code:

```
List<string> _fileNameList = new List<string>();
List<double> _counterFleschScore = new List<double>();
string _fileNameList

foreach (string files in _fileNameList)
            {
                Console.Write(files + "\t\t\t\t");

                foreach (double listingFleschScore in _counterFleschScore)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0:N1}", listingFleschScore);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Comment: What about a grid? E.g. in WinForms you could use a `DataGridView` control to display your results.

Comment: edited. It's a console application.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856845/how-to-best-way-to-draw-table-in-console-app-c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use a `for` loop. The problem is that you have a two, nested `foreach` loops.

Be sure that the score list is at least as big as file list, otherwise you may get an index out of range exception. For a completely safe solution you should add a few checks, which I've omitted for clarity.

```
List<string> _fileNameList = new List<string>();
List<double> _counterFleschScore = new List<double>();

for (var i=0;i<_fileNameList.Count;++i)
{
    Console.Write(_fileNameList[i] + "\t\t\t\t");
    Console.Write("{0:N1}", _counterFleschScore[i]);
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

An improved code would look something like this.

```
var _fileNameList = new List<string>();
var _counterFleschScore = new List<double>();

var count = Math.Min(_fileNameList.Count, _counterFleschScore.Count);
for (var i=0; i < count; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t\t\t\t{1:N1}", _fileNameList[i], _counterFleschScore[i]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know it's that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Why going through all the trouble, just use: [`ConsoleTables`](https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/ConsoleTables), [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConsoleTables/) also available.

There is also [`Console Utilities`](https://github.com/jacobswain/ConsoleUtilities) again [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TableFormatter/) also available.

Comment: The post was having a technical code issue, which is not answered with this at all. This should rather be a comment IMO.

Comment: The OP said: `I want to output the results of my program in a nice looking table.` and my answer provides exactly that. As part of being a software developer we should learn not to re-invent the wheel :-)

Comment: Ok, you have the point with the title, but if someone not too advanced has troubles with nested loops then I don't think any Nuget package is appropriate.

Comment: That's why I also included the related project links including the source code and docs making it a no-brainer!