# C# Show Sql table in console application

Tags: c#, sql, list

How can I show my data table as a list in a console application?

I have a local Database called = MyDatabase.
And I have a table called = tbl_cars.

How can I convert tbl_cars to a list?

Comment: what have you tried by far?

Comment: You are essentially asking for an ADO.NET Tutorial.

Comment: Im new to SQL.
And I have not heard of ADO.net

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856845/how-to-best-way-to-draw-table-in-console-app-c

Answer (score 0):

Fill DataTable from your database and
Create a custom class containing all the fields of tbl_cars table.

```
DataTable dt = FetchTableFromDatabase();

List<Car> lst = new List<Car>();

lst = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
                           select new Car
                           {
                               ID = (int)row["ID"],
                               CarName = row["CarName"].ToString()
                           }).ToList();




private DataTable FetchTableFromDatabase()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connectionString");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_cars", con);

        try
        {
             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
             da.Fill(dt);
             return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
             con.Close();
             con.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Comment: How to I use FetchTableFromDatabase

Comment: Also posted function to retrieve data from database, just put your connectionString...