# Formatting Excel output in Console App C#

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, format

I am working on a little project where the program takes data from a basic Excel Workbook and outputs it into a Console Application. I am currently working on trying to format the output neatly so it does not look like it is all over the place. In the examples below, The first image is the current output and the second is what I would like the output to look like.

**First Output example** (Current):

[image]

**What I'd like it to be formatted like** (Anticipated):

[image]

Here is the current code I have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string nfile = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Assets.xlsx";

        Program p = new Program();
        p.loadDB(@nfile);

    }


    private void loadDB(string file)
    {
        Application excelApp = new Application();

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist");
            return;
        }
        if (excelApp == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excel is not installed");
            return;
        }

        Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(file);
        _Worksheet excelSheet = excelBook.Sheets[1];
        Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;


        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        { 
            Console.Write("\r\n");
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                var val = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelRange.Cells[i, j];
                if (val != null && val.Value2 != null) {
                    Console.Write(String.Format("|{0, -5}", val.Value2 + "\t"));
                }
            }
        }

        excelApp.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The main issue I am trying to figure out is how to use a String.Format type method or another suggestion to neatly format the data output in the console. I have tried using different methods of arrays and forloops all which have failed. This is more of a learning project than anything. If I could get an explanation and point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe smth like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856845/how-to-best-way-to-draw-table-in-console-app-c. You can also "play" with `string.PadLeft()` or `string.PadRight()` methods to gain desired indents.

Comment: @Auditive That is one of the threads I looked at. I cannot figure out how to separate the output from the forloop into a format where I can use the `String.Format` method. 
E.g. `String.Format("{0}, {1}", val.Value2[0], val.Value2[1]);`

Comment: To use paddings in `string.Format` you can specify them at format: `{0,10}` or `{0,-10}` Positive value means **left** padding, negative - **right** padding. Or you can set padding directly to values: `val.Value2[0].ToString().PadLeft(10)` or `val.Value2[0].ToString().PadRight(10)`. It's a point of youself tests to gain needed padding value. For example, you can check this scratch: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9QFy78

Comment: You could also look into using a library for this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49032729/4713952) answer suggests a few different ones.